# python code to change library that is pythonLibrary . to use that code in spring boot application..?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

python code to change library that is python Library .  we can
use that code  in spring boot application..?

i am not get Answer.but i try script Base one using this PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();.but can't import the py librarys

Comment: Mind clarifying this question a bit? What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 2):

To use Python libraries within a Spring Boot application, you can utilize the Jython library, which allows you to run Python code seamlessly in a Java environment.

Comment: Note that Jython currently only works for Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: any refer note u have just share to me pls..